# Moving a class to its own file in python

Tags: python, pygame

I have 2 files one of them is main the other is a player class and im getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/travi/PycharmProjects/game/main.py", line 15, in <module>
player.player1 = player.player(300, 410, 32, 32)
File "C:\Users\travi\PycharmProjects\game\player.py", line 18, in __init__
self.playerImage
AttributeError: 'player' object has no attribute 'playerImage'
```

Heres the source code

```
#file 1############################################
import pygame
import player

pygame.init()

size = WIDTH, HEIGHT = (640, 480)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Game 2")

FPS = 60
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()
animation_speed = 5

player.player1 = player.player(300, 410, 32, 32)
run = True
while run:
pygame.time.delay(50)

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if player.player1.active:
    player.player1.frame += 1
if player.player1.frame >= 2:
    player.player1.frame = 0

player.player1.playerImage = player.player1.cells[player.player1.frame + player.player1.dir]


if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.player1.x > player.player1.vel:
    player.player1.x -= player.player1.vel
    player.player1.dir = 3
    player.player1.active = True
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.player1.x < 640 - player.player1.width - player.player1.vel:
    player.player1.x += player.player1.vel
    player.player1.dir = 6
    player.player1.active = True
elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.player1.y > player.player1.vel:
    player.player1.y -= player.player1.vel
    player.player1.dir = 9
    player.player1.active = True
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.player1.y < 480 - player.player1.height - player.player1.vel:
    player.player1.y += player.player1.vel
    player.player1.dir = 0
    player.player1.active = True
else:
    player.player1.active = False


screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

screen.blit(player.player1.playerImage, (player.player1.x, player.player1.y))

pygame.display.flip()
fpsclock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

##file 2

```
import pygame

class player():
  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.cells = []
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.vel = 5
    self.left = False
    self.right = False
    self.dir = 0
    self.walkcount = 0
    self.active = False
    self.frame = 0
    self.spritesheetplayer = 
    pygame.image.load("playerspritesheet.png").convert()
    self.playerImage

def initialize(self):
    for n in range(12):
        width, height = (32, 32)
        rect = pygame.Rect(n * width, 0, width, height)
        image = pygame.Surface(rect.size).convert()
        image.blit(self.spritesheetplayer, (0, 0), rect)
        alpha = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(alpha)
        self.cells.append(image)
    self.playerImage = self.cells[0]
```

the codes supposed to poll for events and move and animate the character this code was all originally in one file and once i moved some of it to another file these errors started happening how can this code be fixed so that it works

Comment: If your going to post Python code, please make the effort to reproduce your indentation accurately. Otherwise people must guess what it is supposed to be.

Comment: For the last line of `player.__init__()`, did you intend to assign something to `self.playerImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the initial value for playerImage, so for example in your **init** function self.playerImage = None